# JQuery not working in React view without reload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a basic blog app built on Ruby on Rails with React views.

The app has two tables: posts and comments. Each post has a comments section. That section is initially set to "display: none." Each post comes with a button. If you click the button this event happens, which slideToggle()s the comments section into view:

```
 $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

 $('.comments_view').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    if ($(this).text() == 'Comments'){
        $(this).text('Close');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Comments');
    }
});

})
```

This works fine IF the page has been reloaded. However, if the page has not been reloaded, the comments section remains hidden. I can see in the inspector that the section is present. If I manually go into the css and turn the display: none off, it is there. But the JQuery event stops working.

Here is the post component, which contains the button and the comment_container, which is the section I want to target for the toggleSlide(). (Both are very near the bottom. The button is title "Comments.")

```
var Post = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        post: this.props.post, 
        editMode: false
    }
},
handleTitleChange(e) {
    var newPost = this.state.post
    newPost.title = e.target.value
    this.setState({post: newPost});
},
handleAuthorChange(e) {
    var newPost = this.state.post
    newPost.author = e.target.value
    this.setState({post: newPost});
},
handleVideoChange(e) {
    var newPost = this.state.post
    newPost.video = e.target.value
    this.setState({post: newPost});
},
handleContentChange(e) {
    var newPost = this.state.post
    newPost.content = e.target.value
    this.setState({post: newPost});
},
setEditMode: function(){
    this.setState({ editMode: true }); 
},
handlePostUpdate: function(){
    var that = this; 
    $.ajax({
        method: 'PUT',
        data: { post: that.state.post },
        url: '/posts/' + that.state.post.id + '.json',
        success: function(res) {
            that.setState({
                post: res,
                editMode: false
            });
        }
    });
},
handlePostDelete: function(){
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: '/posts/' + that.state.post.id + '.json',
        success: function(res){
            that.props.onDeletePost(that.state.post);
        }
    });
},
render: function(){
    if (this.state.editMode){
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="form_container post col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
                <h4>Edit Post</h4>
                <br />
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <input value={this.state.post.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange} type='text' className='form-control' placeholder="Title" />
                </div>
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <input value={this.state.post.author} onChange={this.handleAuthorChange} type='text' className='form-control' placeholder="Author" />
                </div>
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <input value={this.state.post.content} onChange={this.handleContentChange} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Content" />
                </div>
                <div className='form-group'>
                    <input value={this.state.post.video} onChange={this.handeVideoChange} type="text" onChange={this.handleVideoChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Video URL" />
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handlePostUpdate} className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
        <div>
            <div className="form_container post col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
                <h4>{this.props.post.title}</h4>
                <h5>{this.props.post.author}</h5>
                <p>{this.props.post.content}</p>

                {this.props.post.video && 
                <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video">
                        <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={this.props.post.video} ></iframe>
                </div>
                }
                <br />
                <button className="btn btn-danger spacer pull-right" onClick={this.handlePostDelete}>Delete</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary pull-right" onClick={this.setEditMode}>Edit</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary comments_view">Comments</button>
                <div className="comment_container">
                    <Comments post={this.state.post} key={this.state.post.id} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ); 
    }
}
});
```

I am confused as to why the JQuery stops working on this element, even though it appears to still be in the DOM without a reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the element does not exist when the handler is added. Try leveraging [event bubbling](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) by attaching the handler on a parent element.

Basically, replace this

```
$('.comments_view').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    if ($(this).text() == 'Comments'){
        $(this).text('Close');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Comments');
    }
});
```

with this

```
$(document).on('click', '.comments_view', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    if ($(this).text() == 'Comments'){
        $(this).text('Close');
    } else {
        $(this).text('Comments');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works? So the object isn't originally in the DOM, got that. How does changing it to this syntax allow the JQuery to access the new object?

Comment: Events such as clicks bubble up the stack: for example, clicking on a <li> means also clicking on the <ul> that contains it and on any <div> that might contain the <ul> and so on and so forth. I've just added the handler to the document, which is the parent of everything as all elements are within the document, and then only execute the function if the target - the element that initiated event - matches the '.comments_view' selector. Click the event bubbling link in the answer for more details.